# Close Application with locale?

Tags: task-management, command-line, locale

I use the locale app to automaticly start an obd-app (Torque) when I enter my car. This works well. Now I want to automaticly close that app when I leave my car. As there seem to be no Plugins to achieve this, so my idea is to use the Execute-Plugin to End the task using unix-commands.

Is there a "good" way to close an app? The "kill"-command seems to be a bad decision or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please visit http://www.twofortyfouram.com/support.html

> Q: I see the Shortcut setting opens apps... how do I kill apps?
>
> A: Android treats memory differently than a desktop computer. When leaving an app, it is paused rather than killed, so that returning to it later is faster. If Android needs more memory, it will automatically close apps that have been paused but have not been used recently. Because Android manages memory automatically, "task killer" apps are not necessary. Google has blocked "task killer" apps for Android 2.2 and later.
>
> While it is not possible to "kill" apps on Android, the Shortcut setting can be used to simulate this behavior by bringing the Home screen to the foreground. To do this, simply create a new Shortcut setting that opens the "Launcher" or "Home" app (on HTC devices, the Launcher might be called "HTC Sense"). When the setting is fired, it will bring the Home screen to the foreground, pausing whatever application was previously on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the app I need to "close" is still using a lot of power when running in background, because of continously trying to reading the OBD - Status. I know that usually task killers are nonsense on Android but this is a special case as I do have to close the app manually even if it switches to a background task

Comment: I mark this as the correct solution as it surely helps a lot of others getting here by search. And because I did not want to mark my own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very application-specific, (for torque), so maybe not that helpful for others, but the author from torque answered my question:

```
Send an intent - 'org.prowl.torque.REQUEST_TORQUE_QUIT'  and it should shutdown gracefully
```

Looks like I need a little programming. Well already planned doing a bit more than just my "Hello world" I did until now :)